# C fscanf never returns EOF

Tags: c, scanf

```
int findMaxAndMinValues(FILE *file)
{
    int current_number, max_number = INT_MIN, min_number = INT_MAX;
    rewind(file);
    while ( fscanf(file, "%d", &current_number)!=EOF )
    {
        printf("%d \n", current_number);
        if (current_number > max_number) max_number = current_number;
        if (current_number < min_number) min_number = current_number;       
    }
    printf("Max: %d, Min: %d\n", max_number, min_number);
    return 0;
}
```

So this works fine if the text file is only full of numbers (and spaces/newlines accordingly). But if I have a character in it, it starts looping just the last number it read before encountering the character. 
This is the text file:

```
1
2
3 4 5
16 
12312
hello
```

And the result is just 12312 every line updating endlessly.
Side question: is there a better way to find min/max values of numbers in a text file? Rather than fscanf with %d?
EDIT:Thanks to the answer, here's how I fixed it:

```
int findMaxAndMinValues(FILE *file)
{
    int current_number, max_number = INT_MIN, min_number = INT_MAX;
    int temp;
    rewind(file);
    while ( (temp=fscanf(file, "%d", &current_number))!=EOF )
    {
        if (!temp) { fgetc(file); }
        else {
            printf("%d \n", current_number);
            if (current_number > max_number) max_number = current_number;
            if (current_number < min_number) min_number = current_number;
        }
    }
    printf("Max: %d, Min: %d\n", max_number, min_number);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. You have no code to read the "hello" in your file, so nothing ever reads it and so you never ever get to the end of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the man page. `fscanf()` can return other values besides `EOF`. In particular, if a conversion fails — in particular, if `fscanf()` encounters a non-numeric character — it will return zero to indicate that nothing was read.

You need to act on this information. Otherwise it will return zero the next time as well. And the time after that, ad infinitum.

Comment: "even zero in the event of an early matching failure" Oh I did miss it.. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code loops indefinitely if the program input contains a non-number is that `fscanf()` does not consume input it fails to match, but neither does it return `EOF` in the event of a matching failure.  `EOF` is returned only in the event that the end of the input is reached *before* either a successful conversion is performed or a matching failure occurs, or if a read error occurs.  (A read error is an I/O error -- quite a different thing from a matching failure .)  When your particular program experiences a matching failure, it just loops back around and tries reading the very same input (left waiting to be read) again.

One way to solve the problem would be to compare `fscanf()`'s return value with the number of items expected (1), and break from the loop if you see anything else, whether `EOF`, `0`, or whatever:

```
while ( fscanf(file, "%d", &current_number) == 1 ) // ...
```

Your program would then stop reading numbers when it encounters a non-number; if you instead wanted it to *skip* non-numbers then that could be done, too, but it would be a bit more complicated.

Comment: Yes, this was the case exactly. I added a check and fixed it(code is above)! wow stackoverflow is awesome